# Multiple Dropdown using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am designing and developing a CRUD API where it has 3 dropdowns. If I click on 1 dropdown and select an option it should prompt to another dropdown.

The error I am getting, which is at `handlechange()`, is:

> "`TypeError: Cannot set property 'param_type' of undefined`".

Where is the mistake i am doing?

Below is the code:

```
handleChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.id)
    var errors = this.state.errors
    if (event.target.id.split('_')[0] == 'name') {
        var ids = event.target.id.split('_')
        let szs = this.state.parameters
        szs[ids[1]].param_name = event.target.value
        this.setState({ parameters: szs })
    }
    else if (event.target.id.split('_')[0] == 'type') {
        var ids = event.target.id.split('_')
        let szs = this.state.parameters
        szs[ids[1]].param_type = event.target.value
        this.setState({ parameters: szs })
        console.log(szs)
    }
    else if (event.target.id.split('_')[0] == 'data') {
        var ids = event.target.id.split('_')
        let szs = this.state.parameters
        szs[ids[1]].param_data = event.target.value
        this.setState({ parameters: szs })
    }
    else if (event.target.id.split('_')[0] == 'type_of_configuration_data') {
        var ids = event.target.id.split('_')
        let szs = this.state.parameters
        szs[ids[1]].type_of_config_data = event.target.value
        this.setState({ parameters: szs })
    }
    


    this.setState({
        errors: errors
    })
    
}
```

The render which I do is:

```
 {this.state.parameters[idx_fields].param_type === "list"?
                                                                                                            
 <Col md="2">
                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                
 <Label>Data <span style={{ color: "red" }}>*</span></Label>
                                                                                                                
 <select id={"data" +  '_' + idx_fields} className="form-control select2" value= 
 {this.state.parameters[idx_fields].param_data} onChange={this.handleChange} title="Kind">
                                                                                                                    
 <option value="type_of_configuration_data">Type of Configuration</option>
                                                                                                                    
 <option value="user-defined-data">User Defined Data</option>
                                                                                                                
 </select>
                                                                                                            
 </Col>
                                                                                                            
 :null}
{this.state.parameters[idx_fields].param_data === "type_of_configuration_data"?
                                                                                                            
<Col md="2">
                                                                                                            
<Label>Type of configurations <span style={{ color: "red" }}>*</span></Label>
                                                                                                            
<select id={"type_of_configuration_data" +  '_' + idx_fields} className="form-control select2" value= 
{this.state.parameters[idx_fields].type_of_config_data} onChange={this.handleChange} title="Kind">
                                                                                                                    
<option value="crops">Crops</option>
                                                                                                                    
<option value="tanks">Tanks </option>
                                                                                                                    
<option value="type-of-growing-system">Type Of Growing System </option>
                                                                                                                    
<option value="seeding-units">Seeding Units </option>
                                                                                                                    
<option value="batch-units">Batch Units </option>
                                                                                                                    
<option value="facilities">Facilities </option>
                                                                                                                    
<option value="users">Users </option>
                                                                                                                    
<option value="task-categories">Task categories </option>
                                                                                                                
</select>
                                                                                                            
</Col>
                                                                                                            
:null}
```

Answer (score 0):

What the error says is the object from where you are using the property is not present in other words its `undefined`.

In the code `param_type` is used here, `szs[ids[1]].param_type`. Console and check if the required property is present in `szs[ids[1]]`.

You can use if statement here:

```
if (szs[ids[1]]) {
   szs[ids[1]].param_type = event.target.value;
}
```

or `szs[ids[1]]?.param_type = event.target.value;`